# Statistical significance for longer measurement

Tags: astrophysics, error-analysis, neutrinos, statistics, data-analysis

I recently read that icecube neutrino detector measured neutrinos emmitted from the direction of NGC1068, which is a nearby Active Galactic Nucleus which has reported an excess
of neutrinos from that direction at 4.2 $\sigma$ statistical significance, using 9 years of
iceCube data over which there were 79 data points. Assuming that flux follows spectral index of 3.2.
My question is how much will this significance become after 15 years of operation?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is within our scope. Not because it is off-topic, but because it requires many assumptions. I would expect the answer to occupy many tens of pages in IceCube's applications for ongoing funding.

Comment: @rob to estimate, if consider the spectral index to be 3.2 as predicted by IceCube. That is, flux is proportional to E^(-3.2), then it should be bit more straightforward to calculate, i think.

Comment: I think you should find a recent paper discussing the error budget, and ask a more specific version of your question.

Comment: In all seriousness: if you really need to know, simply send an email to the corresponding icecube email address given on the paper. They probably already have a simulation that properly takes systematic uncertainties into account and answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

In simple cases, the *expected* significance is proportional to the square root of the exposure time. However, $4.2\sigma$ from measurements is only a very crude estimate of the expected significance. And as @Rob notes, this is not a simple instrument with simple data properties.